# Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any' was not found with Storybook js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, storybook

I am getting this error when I make changes to the generated code from running `Storybook.js`. These are the instructions I am following

https://gist.github.com/shilman/bc9cbedb2a7efb5ec6710337cbd20c0c

But because I am adding `StorybookJS` to an existing project, the only commands I've ran are:

```
$ npx -p @storybook/cli@next sb init --story-format=csf-ts
$ yarn add @storybook/addon-docs@next --dev
```

Running `yarn storybook` produces this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/stories/0-Welcome.stories.tsx
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):

  Line 5:1:   Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any' was not found  @typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any
  Line 24:1:  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any' was not found  @typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any
```

The storybook server runs fine but as soon as I make changes to some text and `Storybook` tries to reload the changes, I get the error seen above.

There is a lot of magic that happens behind the scenes of `create-react-app` so I am unaware of how to pinpoint and fix this error. My guess is that a `eslint typescript rule` is missing so upon `Storybook` reloading any type of change, the missing rule error occurs

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/379 Also, if you can find the json file for you eslint, you can just add the rule to see if that resolves.

Comment: @mwilson With `create-react-app` I think the `.eslintrc` file is hidden from me. So I just have to find that JSON file and add the rule?

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure if that app uses something different, but usually there is a file called `tslint.json` which is just a json file with TypeScript lint rules. If you have this in a repo somewhere, I can take a look

Comment: The error message is kind of confusing though. ES screams JavaScript, but `no-implicit-any` is a TypeScript thing. Since it's hanging off the `@typescript-eslint` path, I'm assuming you're working with TypeScript

Comment: @mwilson yes I am! Still trying to find these files. I haven't created them manually, so I assume they're generated somewhere

Comment: It should be at the root. According to the docs, I think you're looking for `.eslintrc.js` (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md)

Comment: @mwilson I am still getting the same error even after adding the `.eslintrc.js` file to the root of my project. My project runs fine on it's own but with `yarn storybook` this error is produced

Comment: Looks like there should be a `.eslintrc.json` file as well (this is the thing that should hold the rules). Do you see that? (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

Comment: @mwilson I added .eslintrc.json and it worked! You answer the question and I will mark it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the `.eslintrc.json` file which describes the rules. You can read more about the file format and options here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Example:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": "error"
    }
}
```

If the error still occurs, try configuring the `no-implicit-any` rule.

Comment: what if we already a have a `.eslintrc.js` file in our project and just added new rules to it and are getting this error?

Comment: I'd make sure you path to the .eslintrc.json is correct. Might not be finding it. You may have better luck posting another question or taking a look at their docs. i haven't worked with this stuff in quite some time.

Comment: fair enough. i actually don't have a `.eslintrc.json` file at all - just the `.eslintrc.js` file.